# Many to Many self reference ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

this is my first post in the community and a have a problema: represent a tree of categories.

First solution: each category has a reference to its parent category.
The problem with this solution is, when I want a subtree of categories I have to query  the database several times, one query per level (height) of the tree and I want some solution more optimized.

Chosen solution: Category (id, name, description) and CategoryxCategory  (`ancestor_id, descendant_id`)
And so to build a sub tree I'll need only one query like this ,

```
 select * from category a, categoryxcategory b.where b.ancestor_id = 1 and 
 b.descendant_id = a.id , gets all sub-categories of the category with id = 1.
```

I've done this solution in java using hibernate, but I could not do in Rails, how do I specify this in the migration and ActiveRecord?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just have ancestor_id and descendant_id be columns in category?

here's a popular gem that does trees for you https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set

Comment: Actually I can't, because I want to build a sub-tree with a single query in the db, doing this solution I would have to query several times the db to get a sub-tree with height > 2. I'll try this gem

Comment: Just to finish the topic what really helps me was [Ancestry](http://rubygems.org/gems/ancestry) , it does exactly what I wanted. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

there is another pattern: Nested Set, which is quite performant on read, but not if you update large trees / insert / reorder. take a look at the [nested_set gem here](https://rubygems.org/gems/nested_set). a self referencing many2many would be essentially a graph, which means, if you're not careful, you could end up with corrupt trees (i.e. nodes with several parents).